# Selecting frames from video for surface extraction using feature matching

Tags: computer-vision, pose, marker

I have a video of an object sitting on an ArUco board. I am currently using ArUco markers to estimate camera transformation and knowing camera intrinsics assessing F.
I use BRISK and FLANN to match the features of each frame and then use F to reject outliers, by calculating the relative transformation of the camera and P I triangulate the points.

The general question is, when you have a video, how do you select some of the frames to extract features from and triangulate?

My problem is that, 1. Using all frames if expensive, 2. many of the frames have a relatively small movement (I am guessing this causes higher error in triangulated points), and 3. frames may be blurry.